# How can I generate static site files from existing CMS-driven dynamic site?

Tags: sitemap, cms

I administer a number of established Textpattern CMS websites and I am investigating the feasibility of generating a static site from the dynamically-created URLs.

The CMS-driven website runs on MySQL + PHP, and although it's relatively lean on resource usage overall, I'd like to bypass the database & PHP overhead where possible, ideally having a server / virtual host for the CMS and a(nother) server / virtual host for the static files to be served from, without the need for MySQL + PHP to be present.

I have the ability to create a sitemap-style inventory of the CMS site page URLs. I can set a `cron` task to run on a schedule, with some `Last-Modified` conditional logic to determine if anything has changed. I can run a copy of the site on `localhost` over http to avoid the overhead of hitting a live site over and over in short succession.

I don't know PHP, so I can't get my head around a CMS plugin to achieve this. I'm relatively competent with `curl`, which may end up being the answer here…but I'm at a dead end on the best route forward.

Is there a static site generator that can take a sitemap-style input file from a live site?

Comment: There is for WordPress.